# Matplotlib Figure to fit tkinter Frame

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

I want to plot in every frame I made in the code below, first I created 6 frames inside one main frame like first fig,then i defined a function to create a figure, and then added this to each frame; the problem is that I cant get the same size or a bit little to fit that frame size, like fig2, i tried to work with `frame1_2.winfo_width()` and `frame1_2.winfo_height()` but cant achieved what I want(one way "to solve"is to add a scrollbar in Yaxes but in this case I really dont want to use scrollbar), any help is really appreciated

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
import matplotlib
import mplcursors
import string
import os
string.ascii_lowercase
n = 5
m = 25
cols11 = string.ascii_lowercase[:m]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, n,size=(n , m)), columns=list(cols11))
newWindow = tk.Tk()
newWindow.state('zoomed')
#newWindow.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350))
newWindow.title('Workflow Chart')
main_frame2_1=tk.Frame(newWindow,bg="pink")
main_frame2_1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
main_frame2_1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1,uniform=1)
main_frame2_1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1,uniform=1)
main_frame2_1.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1,uniform=1)
main_frame2_1.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1,uniform=1)
main_frame2_1.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1,uniform=1)

frame1_1=tk.Frame(main_frame2_1,bg="red")
frame1_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
frame1_2=tk.Frame(main_frame2_1,bg="green")
frame1_2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
frame1_3=tk.Frame(main_frame2_1,bg="black")
frame1_3.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='nsew')
frame1_4=tk.Frame(main_frame2_1,bg="pink")
frame1_4.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='nsew')
frame1_5=tk.Frame(main_frame2_1,bg="red")
frame1_5.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='nsew')
frame1_6=tk.Frame(main_frame2_1,bg="green")
frame1_6.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='nsew')
frame1_2.update()
print(frame1_2.winfo_width(),frame1_2.winfo_height())
r=frame1_2.winfo_width()
s=frame1_2.winfo_height()
def create_plot(dataset1,dataset2,dataset3):
    f, ax = plt.subplots()
    p1,=ax.plot(dataset1,dataset2,linestyle='-', marker='o', color='#0343df',markersize=3,markerfacecolor='red',markeredgecolor='red',label='Actuals')
    p2,=ax.plot(dataset1,dataset3,linestyle='-', marker='o', color='#15b01a',markersize=3,markerfacecolor='#f97306',markeredgecolor='#f97306',label='Target')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()))
    #plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel("Example")
    plt.title("Example")
    plt.legend(loc='best', prop={'size': 8})
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
    #ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle='--', color='#d8dcd6')
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(200))
    #ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle='--', color='#d8dcd6')
    #plt.grid()
    mplcursors.cursor()
    #plt.axhline(0, color='black')
    for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
            item.set_fontsize(8)        
    return f
class VerticalNavigationToolbar2Tk(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
        def __init__(self, canvas, window):
            super().__init__(canvas, window, pack_toolbar=False)

        def _Button(self, text, file,toggle, command):
            img_file = os.path.join(matplotlib.get_data_path(), 'images', file )
            im = tk.PhotoImage(master=self, file=img_file)
            im = im.subsample(2, 2)
            b = tk.Button(master=self, text=text, padx=2, pady=2, image=im, command=command)
            b._ntimage = im
            b.pack(side=tk.TOP)
            return b  
        def _Spacer(self):
            s = tk.Frame(self, width=10, relief=tk.RIDGE, bg="DarkGray", padx=2)
            s.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=1) 
            return s
        def set_message(self, s):
            pass
fig1 = create_plot(df.index,df.iloc[:, 4],df.iloc[:, 6])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=frame1_1)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1) 

toolbar = VerticalNavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1_1)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
fig2 = create_plot(df.index,df.iloc[:, 4],df.iloc[:, 6])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=frame1_2)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1) 
#toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1,pack_toolbar=True)
toolbar = VerticalNavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1_2)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
fig3 = create_plot(df.index,df.iloc[:, 0],df.iloc[:, 2])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig3, master=frame1_3)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1) 
#toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1,pack_toolbar=True)
toolbar = VerticalNavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1_3)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

fig4 = create_plot(df.index,df.iloc[:, 4],df.iloc[:, 6])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig4, master=frame1_4)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1) 
#toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1,pack_toolbar=True)
toolbar = VerticalNavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame1_4)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

newWindow.mainloop()
```

fig1:
[image: frames size equally distributed in big frame]

fig2
[image: first 4 figures bigger than frames]

UPDATE: thanks to acw1668 could fix graphs
[image: fixed charts!!!]

Comment: Add `uniform=1` to all `main_frame2_1.grid_rowconfigure(...)` and `main_frame2_1.grid_columnconfigure(...)`.

Comment: as always thanks so much @acw1668 making a answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @acw1668 comment i could fix this using `uniform=1` to all column and row configure, thanks again